# running nose --with-coverage to get all the package files, but not other dependencies and libs

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

My project folder(yeah - I know it's best practice) is something like:

```
.
├── app.py
├── otherscript.py
├── tests/
└── tools/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── toolfile.py
```

I need `nose --with-coverage` to test the `.py` scripts in the main folder, `tools` folder and exclude the `tests` folder (although I don't really care about excluding that)

When I run basic

```
nose --with-coverage
```

I get coverage on all installed dependencies and libs (flask, requests, etc)

when I run

```
nose --with-coverage --cover-package=folder name (or . or ./)
```

I get coverage for the tests folder. the `tools/__init__.py` file and `app.py` but not for the rest of the scripts:

```
> (opentaba-server) D:\username\pathto\opentaba-server>nosetests --with-coverage -- cover-package=./ ... Name                                      

> Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------- Tests\functional_tests\test_return_json      26      0   100%
> Tests\unit_test\test_createdb                 0      0   100%
> Tests\unit_test\test_scrape                   0      0   100% app     
> 63     15    76%   22, 24, 72-81, 8 8-106, 133 tools\__init__         
> 0      0   100%
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------- TOTAL                                        89     15    83%
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 3 tests in 5.182s OK
```

When I run with the `--cover-inclusive flag` . It just fails with :

```
nosetests-scripts.py: error: no such option: --with-coverage
```

I'll be glad for any help with this

Comment: So it's saying that "--with-coverage" is not a valid option, but only when you ALSO use the option "--cover-inclusive" ?

Comment: @smlstvnh strangely so.

Comment: this is actually the case with `--with-xunit` as well. I spent about 1 hour trying to get the `--xunit-file` option to work without specifying the `--with-xunit` option. Pretty big waste of time...

Comment: Nose's version of coverage is *supposed* to ignore modules in the Python library directory.

Comment: Might be too late, but the last error message looks like you are using an outdated version of nose. Most coverage options are quite recent.

Answer (score 14):

I had a very similar problem with generated code. The solution was to exclude the generated code or tools code in your case only from the reports.

So we now use nosetests to run our tests like

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-inclusive --cover-package=$(PACKAGE)
```

and afterwards, we create the reports manually, so

```
coverage combine
coverage report --omit 'tools/*'
```

Thus, coverage.py will cover your tools package, but they won't show up in the reports.

Answer (score 9):

my **tests/nose_setup_coverage.cfg** file:

```
[nosetests]
verbosity=1
detailed-errors=1

with-coverage=1
cover-html=1
cover-html-dir=../../out/cover

#this is the line that fixed my equivalent of your issue
#by "climbing up" from tests/ but skipping python's **site-packages**
cover-package=..   

where=/Users/jluc/kds2/py/tests
```

adding `cover-package=..` (in the cfg file) and executing from within the tests directory got me to cover all my python directories, but not django and other 3rd party stuff.

This is my directory structure (minus some non-Python stuff):

```
.
├── lib
├── non_app
├── ps_catalog
├── pssecurity
├── pssystem
├── static
├── static_src
├── staticfiles
├── templates
├── tests
└── websec
```

last, though it doesn't seem documented, coverage, as run from nosetests, will pick and use a **.coveragerc** file in the current (test) directory (you can't pass it via commandline or in the nose cfg file, that's for the *cover* plugin).

In that file, the **omit** section allows you finer control on which directories to exclude:

```
omit=/Users/jluc/kds2/env/lib/python2.7/*
     */batch/*
     /Users/jluc/kds2/py/non_app/*
     */migrations/*
```

executing the tests in bash:

`nosetests -c nose_setup_coverage.cfg`

p.s. adding `--cover-erase` to the above, resets coverage

#### edit, FWIW:

I've generally replaced **nose/nose2** with **pytest** as a test runner.  If you don't bring in advanced pytest functionality, it will work just fine with plain old unittests and has a lot more plugins, support and active development.  This is not to diss nose, or to promote pytest, but just saying that's an alternative to consider if you are repeatedly hitting edge cases with nose.

Comment: you save me some shell commands with cover-html=1 (i added also cover-xml=1). thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default tests will not be included in the coverage report. You can make them show up (actually a very good idea to make sure your tests are properly executed, and no duplicate name tests are being ignored) with `--cover-tests`

In any case, `nosetests --help` is your friend. Most likely `--cover-inclusive` flag kills off coverage plugin and other options (for the plugin) become unavailable. You can try to debug it by launching nose through `pdb`.

As alternative you can run coverage as a standalone module launching nose tests.